# With Chrome's, and others' forceful nature of autofill, how do we verify the user is the user?

Tags: html, google-chrome, security, forms, autofill

*Before you consider flagging this as primarily opinion-based. Please read.*

Chrome has become quite insistent on when it will autofill form fields. Across the web, there are complaints about this. Across Stackoverflow, there are plentiful solutions that no longer work, and some get quite hacky to begin with (ie: "generating random input names, and decoding which is which code-side").

In brief testing, Firefox has also become kind of insistent about this. I haven't pushed Firefox much because either browser behaving this way neuters the purpose of asking for a confirmation password.

Every developer in the world has probably used a smartphone and understands how much of a boon autofill *can* be, but in certain situations, it allows us no tool to have any measure of confidence that the user is the user, other than Two-Factor-Authentication (but your password for many-email-accounts is saved too, if you happen to be logged out).

Consider this scenario. I'm in your account, either with autofill or an open-session. I want to take over the account, so the first thing I do is go to change your email address.

- Enter my email address.
- Enter your password which autofill or "Use Password For" will provide *if you've previously saved it*.

I get the email, confirm the email change. Here, the server could also send an email to the old email address, but who gets higher authority--the old or new email address? How much havoc can be done in the meantime? (Email changes can, situationally be delayed, but password changes should be immediate). Much to my frustration, Chrome will provide autofill to each of the standard three boxes in a change-password form.

So in reality, how does we have any reasonable assurance that the user is the user anymore? Ask for a secret answer, but Chrome will put that in autofill too.

The very nature of how autofill *must* work means that the password is available to any scripting beginner that wants it.

Comment: If you’re in an account with saved passwords, all you have to do is read the passwords off the disk. This is an accepted risk that the *user* makes when saving a password for a site and isn’t something the web developer generally needs to deal with. (If you have access to the e-mail account like you describe here, you don’t even need a saved password – just send a password reset.)

Comment: @Ryan I mostly agree with you, but sometimes you just can't let users accept this risk, because you may have the reason to think some of them don't fully understand what they are accepting by choosing the easy option. :) Consider online banking - a lot of users would save their passwords in all kinds of places, and still, that would not be good for either the bank or the affected users. So they implement 2FA - problem solved, everybody happy.

Comment: @GaborLengyel: So by implementing 2FA, saved passwords are okay, which is what the question said.

Comment: @Ryan Not to argue, but the question asked how to properly authenticate the user despite autofill passwords. The answer is a risk-based decision to use multi-factor auth. We are talking about the same thing I think. :)

Comment: @Ryan Thanks! Anyway `This is an accepted risk that the user makes`. I actually doubt that most users even begins to understand the risk generally. 2FA works so long as the attacker doesn't also have access to the email address, or the phone, since many people's method of access is the phone.

Comment: @RegularJoe: I think people do understand the risk that people using their unlocked computer can access the stuff they normally do. Saved passwords aren’t a big part of it. (“that was my friend using my phone” etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you overcomplicated this a bit. :) Yes, autofill passwords are a security risk. In many scenarios, this risk can be accepted, in many others, not so. It depends on your risk assessment / threat model.

If autofill is a threat you decide to mitigate (supposedly because you decide the risk is high enough to justify the cost), you can do so by proper multi-factor authentication. Again, what factors you choose depends on you, but even a simple software token on the user's mobile phone is pretty good, anything beyond that is overkill for many applications and significantly raises the cost, which means the risk needs to be much higher to implement further controls.

So this question is not opinion-based. It should be risk-based.

Edit: Also, I'm not sure what you meant by "the password is available to any scripting beginner that wants it". That is simply not true, they need access to a computer or device where you saved your password. If you are even a little bit careful where you save your passwords, that's not at all easy.

Comment: But with the same device frequently having access to the account, the email address and (if a phone), what are the options? This is why virtually all social apps don't even offer to save your password and force-logout. It's rather frustrating that we web developers can't keep anything protected from what browsers insist on doing. // Yes, any skilled enough "hacker" will get through the strongest web-client protections (rewriting javascripts if they feel it necessary), but browsers today are making the job laughably easy.

Comment: Also @ my `"the password is available to any scripting beginner that wants it"`. If you're in the right environment (any desktop environment included), javascript can tell you what password is in the box. As many users use the same against advice, this is a problem.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't follow you, sorry. If you leave your phone unlocked for others to access, how should any IT measure protect you? It is frankly impossible. (And btw the social apps I use do save my credentials, albeit it's a token and not a password, but it acts the same, and they never force logout.) The same with desktops, in a shared desktop environment, a very basic thing (required by most companies) is that you log out or at least lock your screen. If you allow access to your account, than you allow access to any data associated with that account, including passwords.

Comment: **My apologies, meant to say financial apps. Ugh. I was thinking 'besides social', and typed social** _Sorry!_. Anyway before autofill came along and overrode developer preferences, your password was your single most reliable defense...